# menu href="#pannel" is not working on android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I have the following code that I tested on phonegap (iphone) and it worked, but now when I test directly on android, the menu does not work..

```
<div data-role="panel" id="pannel" data-position="right"  data-display="overlay" data-dismissible="true" data-theme="b" >
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript;" ontouch="home();" onclick="home();">Home</a>
   </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

And then on the footer, i have this code, where the menu should be clicked to show the above..

```
<a data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-role="button" href="#pannel" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-c">&equiv;</a>
```

Please advice. And I'm loading jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js

Answer (score 0):

I figured our why it is not working. The problem was with the css transitions.
I added this line:

> -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;

```
#pannel
{ 
    z-index:1003;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block; 
    top: 30px;
    height: 100%; 
    width: 200px;

    /*background-color: black; */
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
}
```